# why is it giving error "appendChild is null" error and how do i fix it

Tags: javascript

When I am trying to append `td` element to `tr`, it is throwing an error:

> cannot read property appendChild of null

This is my code:

```
var col = prompt('Enter the number of columns, table needs to have');
var row = prompt('Enter the number of rows, the table should have');

function columnCreator() {
    var table = document.querySelector('tableDiv');
    var tableRow = document.createElement('tr');
    table.appendChild(tableRow);

    for (var i = 0; i < col; i++) {
       var tableData = document.createElement('td');
       tableRow.appendChild(tableData);
       var dummyText = document.createTextNode('Table Data');
       tableData.appendChild(dummyText);
    }
}

columnCreator();
```

Comment: tableDiv is an invalid selector

Answer (score 1):

```
var table = document.querySelector('tableDiv');
console.log(table)//undefined
```

Theres nothing like a *tableDiv*, either its an id,class, or nested structure:

```
var table = 
    document.querySelector('#tableDiv') //id
||  document.querySelector('.tableDiv') //class
||  document.querySelector('table > div') //div inside table
||  document.querySelector('div > table');//table inside div
```

Comment: Can you have a `div` element directly under a [`table`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tabular-data.html#the-table-element) element in HTML5 ?

Comment: @JeffNoel i dunno, probably the table wouldnt render

Answer (score 0):

Because your `table` variable is not a valid DOMElement.

`var table = document.querySelector('tableDiv');`

This should probably be `document.querySelector('#tableDiv');` if `tableDiv` is an id.

You can read more about the `document.querySelector` function in the [*MDN Documentation*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).